# website upload error in mail function

Tags: php, mysql, email

i make a mail function and when i upload it on the server the mail function is not working how can i resolve this problem .
i think i  get erro due to

```
smtpMailServer:'localhost',
```

and 
    mailHandlerURL:'bin/MailHandler.php', which is correctly in working condition there is no error in code  where should i change localhost to ?

```
                    ownerEmail:'enquiry@abc.co',
                    stripHTML:true,
                    smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                    targets:'input,textarea',
```

Comment: server may not allow it

Comment: yes when your mail function goes online over internet, you need to use proper mail server like  `gmail`, `smtp.gmail.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use SMTP server for mail transfer from the server 
if you use localhost then its not gives any error but mail is not send.

```
example : "smtp.user.co"
```